# Azure question answering bot that sends images and docs as answer

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I am creating a chat bot using Microsoft question answering service that used to be called QnA, following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/create-test-deploy

I published it to teams via azure, my question is how can I let it answer by sending an image or a document.